# Wifi problem after upgrade 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, upgrade, 15.04, 14.10

After upgrade from Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 i have some problem with my wifi. I don't see option with wireless network on menu bar.

There is report from wireless-info script [wirelees-info](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/master/wireless-info):

1)

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 19 Sep 2015 19:08 CEST +0200
Booted last: 19 Sep 2015 16:04 CEST +0200
Script from: 14 Jul 2015 17:04 UTC +0000
```

2)

```
##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

3)

```
##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.2.0-70-generic #105-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 24 19:49:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7
```

4)

```
##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu
```

5)

```
##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]
Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1201]
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8055 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller [11ab:4363] (rev 13)
Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c04a]
Kernel driver in use: sky2
```

6)

```
##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0a5c:2101 Broadcom Corp. BCM2045 Bluetooth
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0ac8:c302 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. Vega USB 2.0 Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

7)

```
##### PCMCIA card info ##################
```

8)

```
##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

9)

```
##### lsmod #############################

iwlwifi               401083  0 
mac80211              506862  1 iwlwifi
cfg80211              205774  2 mac80211,iwlwifi
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
wmi                    19256  1 mxm_wmi
```

10)

```
##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

11)

```
##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:19
```

12)

```
##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

13)

```
##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

14)

```
##### resolv.conf #######################
```

15)

```
##### network managers ##################

Installed:

NetworkManager

Running:

root       578     1  0 16:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
```

16)

```
##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        88E8055 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet   Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         sky2
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 1.30
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:06:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
```

17)

```
##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true
```

18)

```
##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

19)

```
##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hot-Spot Bulwar]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Hot-Spot Bulwar | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Hot-Spot Bulwar | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WRS_EiTI]] (600 root)
[connection] id=WRS_EiTI | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=WRS_EiTI | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/L70]] (600 root)
[connection] id=L70 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=L70 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto
```

20)

```
##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Warsaw (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
(2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
(2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
(2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
(5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
(5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), DFS, NO-IR
(5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (N/A), DFS, NO-IR
(5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
(57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)
```

21)

```
##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.
eth0      no frequency information.
```

22)

```
##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

23)

```
##### module infos ######################

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-70-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
srcversion:     AF0D27A3E5369F7401307D5
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.2.0-70-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           queues_num:number of hw queues. (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality (int)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (int)
parm:           ucode_alternative:specify ucode alternative to use from ucode file (int)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           bt_ch_inhibition:Enable BT channel inhibition (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           plcp_check:Check plcp health (default: 1 [enabled]) (bool)
parm:           ack_check:Check ack health (default: 0 [disabled]) (bool)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable, 2=enable (default: 0) (int)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           auto_agg:enable agg w/o check traffic load (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           no_sleep_autoadjust:don't automatically adjust sleep level according to maximum network latency (default: true) (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-70-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     1944D882391CC5F32CA6325
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.2.0-70-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-70-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     A289A224DC04F871A44431D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.2.0-70-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)
```

24)

```
##### module parameters #################

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
ack_check: N
amsdu_size_8K: 1
antenna_coupling: 0
auto_agg: Y
bt_ch_inhibition: Y
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_restart: 1
led_mode: 0
no_sleep_autoadjust: Y
plcp_check: Y
power_level: 0
power_save: N
queues_num: 0
swcrypto: 0
ucode_alternative: 1
wd_disable: 0

[mac80211]
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00
```

25)

```
##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
```

26)

```
##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/oss-compat.conf]
install snd-pcm modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { modprobe --quiet snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { modprobe --quiet snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { modprobe --quiet snd-seq-midi ; modprobe --quiet snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
```

27)

```
##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0
```

28)

##### pm-utils ##########################

29)

```
##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x11ab:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:06:00.0 (sky2)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
```

30)

```
##### dmesg | grep iwlwifi #############################

[   62.144763] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[   62.144896] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   62.144951] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: pci_resource_len = 0x00002000
[   62.144953] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: pci_resource_base = ffffc90000658000
[   62.144956] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW Revision ID = 0x0
[   62.145823] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[   62.146092] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN, REV=0x54
[   62.146577] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[   62.175234] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: device EEPROM VER=0x11f, CALIB=0x4
[   62.175237] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Device SKU: 0Xf0
[   62.207045] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 24 802.11a channels
[   62.506823] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode' failed.
[   62.527136] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-5000-4.ucode' failed.
[   62.531093] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-5000-3.ucode' failed.
[   62.532054] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode' failed.
[   62.532825] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-5000-1.ucode' failed.
[   62.532829] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[   62.533051] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: PCI INT A disabled

########## wireless info END ############
```

31)

```
ls /lib/firmware/ | grep iwlwifi

iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode
iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode
iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
```

**--------------------EDIT------------------------------------**

I checked if permissions of `iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode` are correct,

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  340696 Jul 29 08:57 iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
```

and I see that file is owned by root and readable by all. This must be something else.

Comment: You have a wrong kernel 3.2. In 14.04 it should be 3.16, in 15.05 - 3.19. I have no idea how you upgraded without internet connection. I suggest installing Ubuntu 14.04.3 from scratch.

Comment: @Pilot6 Before upgrade my wifi works correct so I can make it without any problem but **after** upgrade i lost my network. I know that install from scratch will resolve my problem but I don't make upgrade to downgrade  now.

Comment: @DavidCole `ifconfig` it is on 11) section of code

Comment: The solution is to install the correct kernel. You can download it using another computer.

Comment: @Pilot6 are you sure, that change kernel will resolve problem? I read something about it and I get information that this is not simple to do this offline

Comment: I am sure that you have a wrong kernel. And wireless driver is in the kernel. I can guide you how to install the correct kernel, if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong kernel for Ubuntu 15.04. You need to install the correct kernel first.

Download these files and copy them to your Home folder.

[linux-image](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.19.0-28-generic_3.19.0-28.30_amd64.deb)

[linux-image-extra](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-extra-3.19.0-28-generic_3.19.0-28.30_amd64.deb)

[linux-firmware](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.143.3_all.deb)

[linux-headers](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.19.0-28-generic_3.19.0-28.30_amd64.deb)

Then run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot.

If your network connection restores, run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

to install meta-package. This will enable kernel updates.

Comment: While this incantation might work, you could improve your answer by explaining 1. Why you think `linux-firmware` is the problem? and 2) Why reinstalling `linux-firmware` would fix the problem.

Comment: @waltinator It is too early to explain. It does not seem to work yet. I will do it later, if the solution is found.

Comment: I see the wrong kernel there. See the updated answer.

Comment: How did you upgrade from 14.10 without network connection and why did you have kernel 3.2 in 14.10? And the previous command should give you errors, without network connection it was useless. You do not have firmware for your adapter and the kernel is wrong. I suggest installing 14.04 or 15.04 from scratch. That will be much easier.

Comment: @Pilot6 thank you so much for you help, change kernel works :)
Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You try this:

```
 sudo apt-get install linux-amd64-efi_ linux-efi
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-get install -f
 sudo apt-get install linux-efi*
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: I wouldn't try your proposition, because change version of kernel resolve my problem with wifi.

Comment: @kuba This answer is a random set of commands. It won't do anything but throw error messages anyway.