# Installation interrupted during upgrade from Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, 14.10

The system was turned off due to power problems *while upgrading to 15.04.*

The OS shows that it's on version 15.04 but some functionalities are not working like WiFi.

*Is there a way to continue the installation from the point it was interrupted?*

Comment: I upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04 and I have problem with wifi too (http://askubuntu.com/questions/676000/wifi-problem-after-upgrade-14-10-to-15-04). But what others functionalities don't work corect at your Ubuntu 15.04?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent system backup this not a big problem, just restore it and start over again.

When not, I recommend to completely reinstall Ubuntu - just install it the way you did before.

I also recommend to format the partition before by using GParted from Ubuntu install media.

Even if Ubuntu system is working somehow in the moment, serious problems may occur later.